# How to Use luminati.io with Phantomjs

Tags: phantomjs, proxies

I have been using proxy ips with phantomjs to scrape data. Has someone used luminati.io with phantomjs? since luminati uses end user computer ips to read pages. Its costly and I need to know if someone has used this already and I should try this.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass `--proxy-auth` and `--proxy` to the command line, for example:

`phantomjs --proxy-auth=lum-customer-YOUR_CUSTOMER-zone-YOUR_ZONE-country-YOUR_COUNTRY --proxy=zproxy.luminati.io:22225 script.js`